# vuetify enlarge image on click

Tags: css, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i have a image gallery on vuetify and trying to enlarge the image using the fullscreen function.

```
<template>
 <v-container class="mt-12">
<v-row justify="center" v-if="!$fetchState.pending">
  <v-col
    cols="4"
    v-for="image in service.data.attributes.gallery.data"
    :key="image.id"
  >
    <v-img
      class="d-flex child-flex"
      :src="`${image.attributes.formats.large.url}`"
      :lazy-src="`${image.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url}`"
      contain
      @click="toggleFullscreen(image.attributes.url)"
    >
    </v-img>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-row v-else>
  <LoadSpinner />
</v-row>
```

and my toogle method

```
methods: {
toggleFullscreen(elem) {
  console.log(elem);
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else {
    alert(
      "Sorry, your browser is too old and doesn't support fullscreen :-("
    );
  }
},
},
```

i have and array coming from a strapi api, the idea is show in the gallery a low res image and when cliking fullscreen the high res version.

problem everytime i click it triggers the alert, so the method is not getting the correct info to work, could be v-img creates a div and uses de image as background?

thanks

pd tried already dialog and overlay but can't figure out how to "attack" individual elements

Answer (score 0):

After trying various libraries and what had to offer vuetify i did a workaround with vanilla css.

I created a variable, when you click on a image passes the url of the image, the template loads a div when this variable is not null with and overlay class to cover the screen.

in my template

```
<v-img 
      v-for="image in service.data.attributes.gallery.data"
      :key="image.id"
      :src="`${image.attributes.formats.large.url}`"
      
      @click="toggleFullscreen(image.attributes.url)"
    />
    <div v-if="selectedImage" class="overlay">
      <v-img
        class="mt-12"
        :src="selectedImage"
        alt=""
        height="95vh"
        contain
        dark
        @click.stop="selectedImage = null"
     >
      </v-img>
    </div>
```

script part

```
<script>
...
export default {
  data() {
    return {
   ...
      selectedImage: null,
    };
  },
  ...
  methods: {
    toggleFullscreen(elem) {
      this.selectedImage = elem;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

css

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2; /* Specify a stack order in case you're using a different order for other elements */
  cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */
}
```